# overloaded private function which is private in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, overloading, private-functions

Usually I have the same structure of my functions:

```
(defn func-name
  ([] (some actions))
  ([ar] (some actions))
  ([ar aar] (some actions)))
```

And usually only one of this variant is `public`. But as You can see from my entry - all my function is `public` because of using `defn` instead of `defn-`. But `defn-` hide **all** function, including all overloaded.

Is there any way to 'hide' only part of overloaded function?

For example, I want to hide an func-name with arity of one and two arguments.

Ofcorse I can hide overloaded function inside one `defn` like this:

```
(defn awesome[]
  (let [func (fn some-func ([] (some actions))
               ([ar] (some actions)))]
    (func)))
```

But I think it's a little bit messy and I'm sure there have to be a way to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know this visibility is defined by `:private` flag in var's `meta`. So this two expressions are equal:

```
(defn ^:private foo [] "bar")
(defn- foo [] "bar")
```

So I think you can control a visibility only of a whole `var`.

I can suggest to use different function names for public and private spaces. I.e `func-name` for public one and `func-name-` for private.

Comment: It doesn't work - the function in that way I did called fine. May be I used meto info not in a right way? Look at my UPD1.

Comment: You didn't get me right :). My point was that you *can't* do it. Not adding meta to your expressions